# UIView with top space Constraint to UIStackView not displayed below Stackview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistackview

My Problem is a bit hard to describe:

I am working on a note app. My "Create a new note" - Screen contains a vertical stackview to display Todo Items associated with the new note.
Below this stackview there is an UIView where the user can add a reminder to the note if he wants to:

[image: Stackview with reminderview below]

The stackview contains a specifix amount of subviews. I don't know this amount when building the user interface instead all the subviews will be added programatically at runtime.
I want the reminder view to always stick below my stackview. So I added a Top Space constraint.

[image: Top Space Constraint]

But this constraint seems to have no impact when adding items to (and therefor enlarging) the stackview programtically.

[image: view overlapping stackview]
[image: this is how it should look]

Edit:
This is the code where i add the subviews:

```
[_todoContainer.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    int y = 0;
    for (NoteTodoEntity* entity in _note.todos) {
        NotinaryTodoView* view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotinaryTodoView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(_todoContainer.frame.origin.x, y, _todoContainer.frame.size.width, 40);
        [view layoutIfNeeded];
        y+=40;
        view.currentEntity = entity;
        [view.todoDeleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(todoActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_todoContainer addSubview:view];
    }
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Show the code where you add subviews

Comment: @Wain I edited my original question

Comment: Try `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` after the loop to give the whole view a chance to update

Comment: @Wain I added [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; Unformtunately it doesn't help (I edited the question again to refelect the changes)

Comment: is it the only view which has issues, views below it are ok? what are they pinned to? add that view to the stack view too...

Comment: I think the problems might occur because you are changing the subviews' frames. When working with a `UIStackView` you are only supposed to inform the UIStackView how it should place and align its subviews and let the UIStackView handle the rest. If you are positioning the subviews manually anyway you might be better of not using a `UIStackView` but a normal `UIView` as your todoContainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was faily simple.
Setting a frame for my programatically-added-views was wrong, instead I had to use constraints and StackView's "addArrangedSubView" Method:

```
for (NoteTodoEntity* entity in _note.todos) {
        NotinaryTodoView* view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotinaryTodoView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
         [view.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = true;
        [view.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.view.frame.size.width].active = true;
        view.currentEntity = entity;
        [view.todoDeleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(todoActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_todoContainer addArrangedSubview:view];
    }
```